# How to bind host directory to ECS in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, docker-container

I have been trying to containerise an application on ECS. I am using terraform to build the infrastructure for the same.

Now, I want to mount a host directory to the container. On plain docker i would go about doing this by using docker run -v `<host_path>:<path_inside_container>`. But I am unable to find the equivalent in terraform for the same.

I have tried the `volume` directive within `aws_ecs_task_definition` but I am unable to read/write from/to the host directory.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my-application"{
    family = <application_family_name>
    task_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskRole.arn}"
    network_mode  = "host"

    volume {
        name = <application_files>
        host_path = "/home/my_app_dir/"
    }

    container_definitions = <container_definitions>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is, add a mapping in task definition after you define the volume in resource `aws_ecs_task_definition`.

@Amal has answered the question with adding `mountPoints` in task definition.  **The `sourceVolume` in task definition has to be the same name in `volume` of the resource.**

What I need to mention here is,

The part of @amal's volume code is copied from Cloudformation templates, but can't be used in terraform. There is no list with maps supported in resource `aws_ecs_task_definition` currently . Your exist volume code is fine.

If you need to add more volumes, use this way

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my-application"{
    family = <application_family_name>
    task_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskRole.arn}"
    network_mode  = "host"

    volume {
        name = <application_files>
        host_path = "/home/my_app_dir/"
    }

    volume {
        name = <application_files_2>
        host_path = "/home/my_app_dir-2/"
    }

    container_definitions = <container_definitions>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BMW for clearing that that `volumes` block was from cloudformation. I was searching terraform docs.

Answer (score 4):

AWS ECS allows you to create a data volume with name and sourcePath in task definition

```
"volumes": [
    {
      "name": "applicationData",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/ecs/applicationData"
      }
    }
  ]
```

and mount points in Container definitions.

```
"mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "applicationData",
          "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        }
      ]
```

The above shown are cloudformation snippets, you may try to create the same with these Terraform [Apis](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html) .

Comment: Thanks @Amal for your answer. I did not realise that the `volume` block from your answer is from cloud-formation (I haven't used it any time.). Thanks @BMW for clearing that up.

Comment: @Yash Thanks for pointing out. I wanted to share the AWS concept. Let me update and mention about cloudformation.

Comment: @Amal your solution works but with one issue for me. I have a config file that is over written by the default config file from the container. e.g. when the container mounts it overwrite the file. I need the file on the host to overwrite the containers. Any idea?